# Can't calculate the area between a quarter of a circle and a line

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to calculate the area between two curves, the top curve being $y=\sqrt{1.825^2-(x+5)^2}-2.225$, which is the equation for the circle $(x+5)^2+(y+2.225)^2=1.825^2$ solved for $y$, and the bottom curve being $y=-89/40$ on the interval [-6.825, -5]. Below is the integral that *should* do so.
$$\int_{-6.825}^{-5}\sqrt{1.825^2-(x+5)^2}-2.225-(-89/40)dx$$
However, Symbolab threw the error message "Cannot solve". Was that because of something to do with the top curve having been part of a circle? I figured that the provided bounds made the top curve a function.

On a different but likely not completely unrelated note, graphing the top curve in Desmos yields an undefined point at $x=-6.825$.

Why can't I calculate the area between these curves with this integral, and how can I instead calculate it?

Comment: Have you made an image?

Comment: At first you must calculate the intersection points of the line with the circle.

Comment: https://imgur.com/ypObT8b

Comment: WA has no problem with calculation of this integral. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5B1.825%5E2-(x%2B5)%5E2%5D%2FPi%2F1.825%5E2,%7Bx,-6.825,-5%7D%5D

Comment: For the upper bound i have got $$x=-3.175$$

Comment: Note that $2.225=\dfrac{89}{40}$.